# get sibling value from array based on a value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of items which is formatted as per the below:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Title 1",
    "value": "1"
  }
  {
    "text": "Title 2",
    "value": "2"
  }
]
```

I have a function which returns a `value` from this array. I need to get the text from the array using the value. So, if I have `1` then I need to search the array and to retrieve `Title 1`

Strugling on what the correct term to search for is?

Comment: Filter, you're after the logic to filter the array by a sub key's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create some kind of a search function. Function below finds all elements with `o.value` of `param1` in array-structured objects list of `param2`. You can further extend this example to return only one element of an array, or to return a collection of `o.text`s.

```
let i = [
  {
    "text": "Title 1",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "text": "Title 2",
    "value": "2"
  }
];

function getByValueFrom(value, array) {
  let a = [];

  a = array.filter(e => {
    return e.value === value;
  });

  return a;
}

let retVal = getByValueFrom('2', i)

console.log(retVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to TaurusHORN answer, make it shorter.

```
    function getByValueFrom(value, array) {
       return (array.filter(e => {
         return e.value === value;
      }));
    }

    const retVal = getByValueFrom('2', i)[0].text;
```